# Inheriting child components from vue.js json parent component

Tags: vue.js

Parent.Vue

```
msg:"",
parentData: {msg:[]},
    methods: {
        response(file, respone) {
        this.msg = respone
        console.log(respone)
        },
    }
```

Child.Vue

```html
<template>
  <div class="result">
    <p>{{parentData.msg}}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

I want to inherit the json data received from the parent component as a child component.

The json data format is uploaded as a photo.

[image]

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: @nada 
json data is received from the backend and the value cannot be passed from the parent component to the child component.

Comment: @nada 
I want to inherit the json data contained in `msg` to a child component.

Comment: @nada 
Post edited

Comment: @nada Try it...```msg:"",
                        parentData: {msg:'{{msg.rate_adult}}'},
                    }),``` Failed

Comment: @RynGan it is still not very clear what you have tried to do but the conventional was is using props like Phile said. Follow the link Phil gave and see how to pass props to child components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *props* to pass data from parent to child components.

For example

```js
Vue.component('Child', {
  props: ['parentData'],
  template: `<div>
  <h2>Child</h2>
  <pre>parentData = {{ parentData }}</pre>
  </div>`
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({ msg: {} }),
  methods: {
    response (file, response) {
      this.msg = response
      // console.log(response)
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    // simulate loading data
    setTimeout(() => this.response(null, {
      file_name: 'result.jpg',
      font_color: 'red',
      info_text: 'Clean'
    }), 2000)
  }
})
```

```css
h1, h2 { margin: 0 }
div {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>Parent</h1>
  <pre>msg = {{ msg }}</pre>
  <!-- pass msg to child via the parent-data prop -->
  <child :parent-data="msg"/>
</div>
```

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props